# How to transform the nested list in one column of dataframe to one dimension list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

```
   videoID  long   lat   viewerCount
0      225   -10   1.8     [1,[3,4]]
1      228    12  23.0         [5,5]
2      123    10  20.0  [1,[2, [3]]]
```

I have dataframes like shown above. What I'm trying to do is to convert the values of viewerCount to single Dimension array. The expected output is shown below:

```
   videoID  long   lat viewerCount
0      225   -10   1.8   [1, 3, 4]
1      228    12  23.0      [5, 5]
2      123    10  20.0   [1, 2, 3]
```

I've tried many resources but failed to come to solution. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance to life saver who'll solve it.

Comment: You say "I've tried many resources but failed to come to solution". Improve your question by including the code that you've tried that didn't work in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert it to string, remove all square brackets and spaces and finally split it by `','`:

```
In [28]: df['viewerCount'] = \
             df['viewerCount'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[\[\s\]]', '').str.split(',')

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
   videoID  long   lat viewerCount
0      225   -10   1.8   [1, 3, 4]
1      228    12  23.0      [5, 5]
2      123    10  20.0   [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: excellent Idea. You're a smart person. Thanks life savior. Many Many thanks.

Comment: But as my loop increase and this statement executes again and again. The number of " ' " increase like instead of too many layers of " [ " or " ] ", I'll now have layers of (single quotation ) " ' ".

Comment: @ZuhaibAsad, please consider adding a __reproducible__ sample data set to your question and your desired data set. My solution doesn't need any loops...

Comment: Its done. I was using some other data structures but your help was very much helpful.

Comment: @ZuhaibAsad, glad i could help :)